# How to get the bibliography section numbered?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, numbering, templates

I'm using a latex template to be found [on Github](https://github.com/rucsgss/thesis/blob/master/ruthesis.cls)
to write my dissertation. I want to make "References" a numbered **subsection** of a chapter, but I don't know how to make changes to the cls file.

I think I need to make some modifications to line 170 to 219. Could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: You should never modify a class file unless you are the author and owner of the file.

Comment: That class is more than 20 years old. Nothing good can come from that. Do you really need to use it?

Comment: If so, can I write a command to override it so that I can create a numbered section for the reference?

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\unnumberedsection}{\section}{}{}` <- completely untested. It isn't worth digging up the graves of our grandfathers.

Comment: Since I'm not an expert of Latex, it seems the class is still ok to satisify my university's requirement except the reference part...

Comment: Maybe `\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\unnumberedsection}{\chapter}{}{}` will be better for your needs.

Comment: @Johannes_B - I think you meant to write `\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\unnumberedchapter}{\chapter}{}{‌​}`? Anyway, I think this should be the answer to the OP's query.

Comment: @Mico No, i really meant to write that. You cannot argue with the genuity of templates. I added an answer.

Comment: `\newcommand{\unnumberedsection}[1]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{unnumberedsection}{#1}\typeout{#1}}`

Comment: @Johannes_B "more than 20 years old" is maybe not a good argument when using TeX :)

Comment: @samcarter Good point, but once in a while somebody is looking at bug reports. I bet that class is unmaintained for a while.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Ah, I found `ruthesis.cls` not via the OP's link but by searching github for `ruthesis.cls`. Through this search, I found 2 sites - [cmansley/ruthesis](https://github.com/rucsgss/thesis/blob/master/ruthesis.cls) and [hwoithe/ruthesis](https://github.com/hwoithe/ruthesis/blob/master/ruthesis.cls) -- that use `\def\thebibliography#1{\unnumberedchapter{References}...` etc. My mistake for assuming that the OP's link uses the same code! I should have dug deeper and noticed that whereas the OP's link says its version is 1.2, the other two links say their version is 1.3 -- from 2009.

Comment: @Mico Welcome to template hell. Most troubeling for me, the repo linked above is the universitys CS guys.  :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B - That's depressing and troubling indeed, that the Rutgers U Computer Science guys would provide a link to a clearly obsolete version even though a much newer version is around and rather easy to locate.

Comment: @Mico Newer version? I think i saw just 5 or 6 different versions of `ruthesis.cls` (for Rutgers U, not the file `ruthesis.cls` for Rice U). One even had file version 1.0 (2011) instead of version 1.3 from 1995. WHAT??

Answer (score 5):

Not taking into account that the class is very old, it apparently does its job. Never touch a running system.

Add the following code block in your preamble to get a numbered bibliography that matches the other entries.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\unnumberedsection}{\chapter}{}{‌​}
```

[image: numberedBibliography]

---

As [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) pointed out, other versions of the same class file are available.

If the above code did not work, try

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\unnumberedchapter}{\chapter}{}{‌​}
```

Luckily, LaTeX class files do have a file date, as well as a version number and a clear copyright and authorship note. Some even have a change history.

Don't bother, nobody respected that and there are multiple versions of the same <s>fail</s>, sorry, file out there.

Comment: Thank you!@Johannes_B I'm wondering if it is possible to change it to a subsection. that is, 3.1. References....?

Comment: @416171205 What do you really want? Guess i answer your question, what will be the next question? Please think about what you finally want and add (edit) it to the question.

Comment: Really sorry for that. I just saw your answer - that answered what I asked, but I just realized what I actually wanted is a "subsection".@Johannes_B

Comment: @416171205 A subsection of what?

Comment: A subsection of a chapter@Johannes_B. Say for example, a subsection of the second chapter. It should be 2.1 References...

Comment: @416171205 This is a completely different question and a completely different task and a completely different answer/approach. Please search the site for *multiple bibliographies* or *bibliography per chapter*.